# defining a "VARIANT" column type in SQLite?

Tags: types, sqlite

Is there a way to define a column type in SQLite that holds any datatype that SQLite supports?

I have unsigned chars, signedchars, unsigned ints, signed ints, UTF-8 chars and blobs that I want to populate in a single column.

Reference to any literature is also appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Just don't put a type in the column declaration, so it has NONE affinity

```
create table my_table(my_col);
```

SQLite has a unique dynamic typing system.  It has per-value typing, but if you specify a column type, SQLite will determine a type affinity (TEXT, NUMERIC, INTEGER, REAL, NONE).  It then attempts to coerce each value to that affinity.

The actual supported types are NULL, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT, BLOB.  See [Datatypes in SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Variant is the default in sqlite, the reverse is harder. It is difficult to define a column that can only tolerate numbers and will throw an exception when you want to insert "this is text".

You can assert that a column can only store integers with a check constraint:

```
CHECK(typeof(x)='integer')
```