# InvalidCastException when using datareader.getString() on a string field that contains numerical value

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have a field in a sqlite database, we'll call it `field1`, on which I'm trying to iterate over each record (there's over a thousand records). The field type is `string`. The value of `field1` in the first four rows are as follows:

```
DEPARTMENT
09:40:24
PARAM
350297
```

Here is some simple code I use to iterate over each row and display the value:

```
while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
{
     strVal = sqlite_datareader.GetString(0);
     Console.WriteLine(strVal);
}
```

The first 3 values display correctly. However, when it gets to the numerical entry 350297 it errors out with the following exception on the `.getString()` method

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll
```

I've tried casting to a string, and a bunch of other stuff. But I can't get to the bottom of why this is happening. For now, I'm forced to use `getValue`, which is of type `object`, then convert back to a string. But I'd like to figure out why `getString()` isn't working here.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's how I currently deal with the problem:

```
 object objVal;  // This is declared before the loop starts...

 objVal = sqlite_datareader.IsDBNull(i) ? "" : sqlite_datareader.GetValue(i);
 if (objVal != "")
 {
     strVal = (string)objVal;
 }
```

Comment: Did you try GetInt() instead of GetString(), for the one that's an integer? What is returned by GetValue(index).GetType()? What is the type of the actual value in that column?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I can't switch to GetInt(), because it's a string data type in the database. When I run `GetType` as you suggested, each type resolves as `System.String` I almost feel there's something inherently flawed here...

Comment: The exception is telling you that you are trying to cast something to a string that is not a string. Maybe its `DBNull.Value`. I don't know. But it's not a string. You can use GetValue() to find out what it actually is, and act accordingly. How do you "convert back to a string"? `(string)obj`, or `System.Convert.ToString()`? As far as "inherent flaws" go, by a vast margin the least tested and most poorly-understood code getting executed there is your own, and it's written by the least experienced developer.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I updated the question to show how I'm currently dealing with the problem. And by me saying inherently flawed, I'm referring to my brain :) No but I agree with you entirely, I'm quite sure I'm doing something wrong. That was the frustration talking, no offense intended. Also, I want to point out that I did verify that it's bugging out at the referenced numerical value. Not at a null value elsewhere. If I remove this numerical entry, it runs fine.

Comment: Fair enough! If that code doesn't throw an invalid cast exception, though
, I'd bet money that you were running into a null value, which couldn't be cast to String. Unless SQLite has... [oh... dear God... kill it with fire... IT'S IN THE HOUSE...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731212/defining-a-variant-column-type-in-sqlite)

Comment: @EdPlunkett It really does seem that way... The thing is I can verify that's not the case. I can add this `strVal = sqlite_datareader.IsDBNull(0)? "" : sqlite_datareader.GetString(0);` and I get the same error. I can move the numerical string to anywhere in the database, and it will error out at whatever location I move it to... So it can't be a null issue... No pun intended. The `isDBNull` method was included for areas elsewhere, that are actually null.

Comment: I'm curious. When you hover over a method name, it will tell you the value type it returns.  So if you hover over the `GetValue()` in `sqlite_datareader.GetValue()`, what value type does it say it will return?

Comment: ... and the reason I ask it because it would seem that even though your sqllite column is defined as a string, the method `sqlite_datareader.GetString()` seems to take the raw value (in your case `350297`) and assume it's whatever that value's native type might be. In the case of `350297` it seeme to think it's an int, so sqlite must be offering up that value as `350297` instead of `"350297"`.  So when you use `GetString()` it throws an error. If you KNOW this is happening, then it seems like relying on `GetValue()` might be a better option. But, I don't know what type it returns by default.

Comment: ... and one last thing. Are you SURE that the sqlite column is defined as a `string` / `varchar()`?  In sqlite, if you don't define the type of a column, it will allow any type.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Actually, any column will accept any type regardless of what column type was specified. Declaring a type only sets a type affinity (a type to which data will attempt to be converted before storing), but it never limits the type of data that can be stored.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Thanks for the input. `GetValue(0)` returns an object. Yes I'm sure of the defined schema. And everything you said mimics the train of thought I went through almost exactly. C Perkins gave a great answer explaining the behavior here check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the question should have included is

1. The table schema, preferrably the CREATE TABLE statement used to define the table.
2. The SQL statement used in opening the `sqlite_datareader`.

Any time you're dealing with data type issues from a database, it is prudent to include such information.  Otherwise there is much unnecessary guessing and floundering (as apparent in the comments), when so very useful, crucial information is explicitly defined in the schema DDL.  The underlying query for getting the data is perhaps less critical, but it could very well be part of the issue if there are CAST statements and/or other expressions that might be affecting the returned types.  If I were debugging the issue on my own system, these are the first thing I would have checked!

---

The comments contain good discussion, but a best solution will come with understanding how [sqlite handles data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) straight from the official docs.  The key takeaway is that sqlite defines type affinities on a column and then stores actual values according to a limited set of storage classes.  A type affinity is *a type to which data will attempt to be converted before storing*.  But (from the docs) ...

> The important idea here is that the type is recommended, not required. Any column can still store any type of data.

But now consider...

> A column with TEXT affinity stores all data using storage classes NULL, TEXT or BLOB. If numerical data is inserted into a column with TEXT affinity it is converted into text form before being stored.

So even though values of **any storage class** can be stored in **any column**, the default behavior should have been to convert any numeric values, like `350297`, as a string before storing the value... *if the column was properly declared as a TEXT type*.

But if you read carefully enough, you'll eventually come to the following at the end of section *3.1.1. Affinity Name Examples*:

> **And the declared type of "STRING" has an affinity of NUMERIC, not TEXT.**

So if the question details are taken literally and `field1` was defined like `field1 STRING`, then technically it has NUMERIC affinity and **so a value like `350297` would have been stored as an integer, not a string**.  And the behavior described in the question is precisely what one would expect when retrieving data into strictly-typed data model like `System.Data.SQLite`.

It is very easy to cuss at such an unintuitive design decisions and I won't defend the behavior, but

1. at least the results of "STRING" type are clearly stated so that the column can be redefined to TEXT in order to fix the problem, and
2. "STRING" is actually not a standard SQL data type.  SQL strings are instead defined with TEXT, NTEXT, CHAR, NCHAR, VARCHAR, NVARCHAR, etc.

**The solution** is either to use code as currently implemented:  Get all values as objects and then convert to string values... which should be universally possible with .Net objects since they should all have `ToString()` method defined.

Or, redefine the column to have TEXT affinity like

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
   ...
   field1 TEXT,
   ...
)
```

Exactly how to redefine an existing column filled with data is another question altogether.  However, at least when doing the conversion from the original to the new column, remember to use a `CAST(field1 AS TEXT)` to ensure the storage class is changed for the existing data.  (I'm not certain whether type affinity is "enforced" when simply copying/inserting data from an existing table into another or if the original storage class is preserved by default.  That's why I suggest the cast to force it to a text value.)

Comment: Man, this was very enlightening. I've done a good deal of work in SQL Server, but this is my first go-around with sqlite. This 'affinity' thing is new to me. I'm actually importing the data from a pdf with the `pdftotext` cli tool. Then I plan on cleaning the imported table up and moving to another table. When I began the cleaning, I ran into this issue. I actually tried defining the column as `varchar` and I got the same error. I haven't tried `text` yet though, but I will. I also tried `CAST` but not with the text type. Thanks again I hope this answer eventually gets the upvotes it deserves.

Comment: UPDATE: This is 100% correct. String's affinity for `Numeric` causes the problem. Casting or changing the data type to `varchar` or `text` solves the issue. I tried `varchar` before and got a false negative because I didn't check for nulls. The interesting thing is that there weren't any nulls, but I'm assuming this goes back to the 'affinity' issue.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! :)  I feel for you in getting to know sqlite, especially after using a robust database server.  As an embedded, server-less database I have learned to really enjoy sqlite, but type type affinity and automatic conversions can be a real pain if not careful.  I tend to be a data-type purist since I'd rather take my time coding for strict types than trying to debug rouge data like your example. :)